# Geary's Document Font

Tags: fonts, geary

I have a vision impediment that means I can't easily read the default document font in Geary, the email client.

Is there any way to change the font preference?

Comment: On such a new program I would contact the makers via their website.  you will probably get the fastest response there. Btw do you have the new version that was released on the 3rd of October (yesterday)?

Answer (score 3):

user198801's answer is correct, that's one way to change the display font.  Users can also override the installed CSS by placing a CSS file in their ~/.config/geary/user-message.css.  However, this only changes the font in the message viewer, not the composer.

We do have an outstanding ticket to respect the OS's document font and size in both the viewer and the composer: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4508  That's probably the most robust solution for this problem.

Comment: A patch to use the system document font has landed in master and should be available for version 0.8: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=713746

Answer (score 1):

please look under `/usr/share/geary/theming`.

`message-viewer.css` is what you are looking for.

Comment: could you provide some information on how to modify this file? Is there documentation available?